# What could be the possible origin of boron found in the Martian soil if not from ancient groundwater?

Tags: planet, mars, planetary-formation

In a recent observation reported in the ScienceAlert article '[Boron has been detected on Mars for the first time](http://www.sciencealert.com/boron-has-been-detected-on-mars-for-the-first-time)" reporting that

> The Curiosity rover has found boron on the surface of Mars, indicating that, at some point, the Red Planet had long-term habitable groundwater.

Making the analogy that

> Boron here on Earth is associated with sites where there was once lots of water, but it's since evaporated away - like California's Death Valley.

However, they state that this may not necessarily be the case for Mars, so

**What could be the possible origin of boron found in the Martian soil if not from ancient groundwater?**

Comment: Meteoric source?

Comment: That, or Martian soil just tends to be richer in boron compared to Earth soil anyway.

Comment: Either are possibilities, also possibly volcanic - there is bound to be research somewhere about this.

Answer (score 2):

Research published in the *PLoS One* paper "[Boron Enrichment in Martian Clay](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0064624)" (Stephenson et al. 2013) suggest a volcanic origin for the boron, in the chemical analysis of a Martian meteorite (found in Antarctica), they explain:

> A straightforward geochemical interpretation of our results is that boron, a relatively volatile and soluble element, was **first concentrated in the fluid dregs of lava** (4–7 ppm boron has been detected in the late stage mesostasis of other [nakhlites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakhlite)) and **then became further concentrated by any groundwater or hydrothermal fluids** that came into contact with the rock.

Further modelling reported in the paper "[Partitioning of light lithophile elements during basalt eruptions on Earth and application to Martian shergottites](https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/handle/1810/246646)" (Edmonds, 2014), also point towards a volcanic origin. Their modelling is based on analyses of [shergottite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shergotty_meteorite) pyroxenes (Martian meteorites), stating that observed elevated boron alongside other light lithophile elements or LLE are to do with the earlier mantle chemical processes, extrapolated from those observed on Earth:

> The range in LLE and trace elements observed in shergottite pyroxenes are instead consistent with concurrent mixing and fractionation of heterogeneous melts from the mantle.

Also, a volcanic origin is suggested in the Goldschmidt Conference Abstract "[Boron isotopes in the nakhlites: Implications for crustal fluids on Mars](https://goldschmidtabstracts.info/2008/889.pdf)" (Spivak-Berndorf et al. 2008), also based on analyses of nakhlites:

> The lack of isotopic fractionation between the igneous and
>   secondary alteration phases in the nakhlites indicates that (1)
>   the B in the fluid that deposited the [iddingsite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iddingsite) was derived
>   from the primary igneous minerals and (2) there was minimal
>   B isotope fractionation between the fluid and the iddingsite